# Make a program run linear in C

Tags: c

So based in the following problem from [cumulative sum query](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CSUMQ/) I created the solution. But is any other way to solve the problem in C with linear complexity O(N)?

Problem description:

> William Macfarlane wants to look at an array.
>
> You are given a list of N numbers and Q queries. Each query is
>   specified by two numbers i and j; the answer to each query is the sum
>   of every number between the range [i, j] (inclusive).
>
> Note: the query ranges are specified using 0-based indexing.
>
> **Input**
>
> The first line contains N, the number of integers in our list (N <=
>   100,000). The next line holds N numbers that are guaranteed to fit
>   inside an integer. Following the list is a number Q (Q <= 10,000). The
>   next Q lines each contain two numbers i and j which specify a query
>   you must answer (0 <= i, j <= N-1). Output
>
> **Output**
>
> For each query, output the answer to that query on its own line in the
>   order the queries were made.

Here is the solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct node {
    int first;
    int last;
};

int sum_array(int *array, int first, int last) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    FILE* input = fopen("share.in","r");

    int N = 0;
    fscanf(input,"%d",&N);

    int *array = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&array[i]);
    }

    int Q = 0;
    fscanf(input,"%d",&Q);

    struct node query[Q];

    for (int i=0; i < Q; i++) {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&query[i].first); 
        fscanf(input,"%d",&query[i].last); 
    }

    fclose(input);

    int sum = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < Q ; i++) {
        int first = query[i].first;
        int last = query[i].last;

        sum = sum_array(array,first,last);

        printf("Number of queries : %d , sum is %d\n",i ,sum);
    }

    free(array); 
    return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

The answer given is good. But for some reason **I couldn't make it work**.

So here is the code rewritten and if someone can explain me what I do wrong I will be happy! Keep in mind we want the range to be **[first,last]**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct node {
    int first;
    int last;
};

int sum_array(int *array, int first, int last) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    FILE* input = fopen("share.in","r");

    int N = 0;
    fscanf(input,"%d",&N);

    int *array = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int *integralArray = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));    

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&array[i]);
        integralArray[i] = array[i] + ((i > 0) ? array[i-1] : 0);
    }

    int Q = 0;
    fscanf(input,"%d",&Q);

    struct node query[Q];

    for (int i=0; i < Q; i++) {
        fscanf(input,"%d",&query[i].first); 
        fscanf(input,"%d",&query[i].last); 
    }

    fclose(input);

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Q ; i++) {
        int first = query[i].first;
        int last = query[i].last;

        sum = integralArray[last] - integralArray[first - 1];

        printf("Number of queries : %d , sum is %d\n",i ,sum);
    }

    free(array); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Preprocessing. Store `a[0] + ... + a[j]` at a[j]. This way you can answer a query in constant time.

Comment: You mean what to replace? The sum function?

Comment: Store the sum of all the elements up to `j` in `a[j]`. That way when you have a query just return `a[last] - (first > 0 ? a[first - 1] : 0)`

Comment: @dmg and how can that make it linear? Can you please explain yourself more. I know you know it but if you want make a full answer!

Comment: After your update change the line to `sum = integralArray[last] - (first > 0 ? integralArray[first - 1] : 0);`

Comment: regarding the malloc calls:  1) in C, do not cast the returned value,  2) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful (!= NULL)

Comment: regarding the fscanf calls: always check the returned value to assure the input/conversion operation was successful

Comment: this problem is perfect for `prefix sum` or `scan`. have a look at this technique.

Answer (score 2):

You'd form the integral array. Modify to something like:

```
int *array = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
int *integralArray = (int*)malloc(N * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    fscanf(input,"%d",&array[i]);
    integralArray[i] = array[i] + ((i > 0) ? integralArray[i-1] : 0);
}
```

So the element at `integralArray[i]` is the sum of all elements in `array` from `0` to `i`.

Then, to get the sum from `a` to `b`, where `a > b`, `integralArray[b]` is the sum from `0` to `b` and `integralArray[a]` is the sum from `0` to `a` so you can just compute `integralArray[b] - integralArray[a]` to get the total from `a` to `b`. Intuitively, `integralArray[b]` includes the numbers you want but it also includes the numbers up to and including `a`. You don't want those so you take them off again.

Vary appropriately for inclusion or exclusion of the number at `a` and the number at `b`. That as given will include the number at `b` but not that at `a`. You could adjust your `integralArray` to be one earlier (so `integralArray[b]` is the sum from 0 to `b-1`) or adjust your indices.

Comment: and what about the sum function? Where do I put these? Sorry for my nobbility! but I really lost myshelf

Comment: Oooh and each element in the `integralArray[i]` is the sum of each querry?

Comment: ok again I didn't understand. Sorry but I don't need the sum function with that? And the `i` isn't always greater than 0?

Comment: I wrote the sum like this : `sum = integralArray[last] - integralArray[first - 1];` cause we want [i,j] (I don't know if I do it right. But the output isn't correct. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Minor: consider different malloc style: `int *array = malloc(N * sizeof *array);`.  Cast not needed and IMO easier to code/maintain.

Comment: Assuming `last` and `first` greater than 0, probably `integralArray[last-1] - integralArray[first-1]` if you wanted the sum in the range [first, last). Each `integralArray` entry is the sum of everything up to _and including_ the number at that index.

Comment: @Tommy I wanted [first,last], but as I point out I take flase ouputs. What am I doin't wrong? See the update of my code and tell me

Comment: @Opo the way I'd written it the `integralArray` wasn't actually the sum it claimed to be. Fixed. Also you should check for `first > 0` before assuming that `first - 1` is a safe index.

Comment: @Tommy ok `sum = integralArray[last] - ((first > 0) ? array[first-1] : 0);` , but even now nothing worked. Can you please make a full post of the code? What is going wrong anyway?

Comment: @Opo I'm just making up input data, which looks good to me. Is share.in publicly available? I'd rather not post incorrect code.

Comment: @Tommy if you see the link of the problem you'll see the input example.